# Will Java's split override the length of array even if it is pre initialized?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String [] arr = {" "," "," "," "};  // String arr = new String[4];
String splitThis = "Hello, World, There";
arr = splitThis.split(","); 
arr[3] = "YAY";
```

The fourth line throws an Array Index Out of bounds Exception. Even though the array is of length 4.
How to progress in this case?

Comment: You realize that `split()` returns an entirely *distinct* array, right? So `arr` points to a different array than your original one.

Comment: Assigning to an array variable doesn't write into the array; it points the variable to a new array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the array *isn't* length 4. The array is of length 3, because it's the result of the split operation.

Your code is effectively just:

```
String splitThis = "Hello, World, There";
String[] arr = splitThis.split(","); 
arr[3] = "YAY";
```

Once you've done an assignment to a variable, its previous value doesn't matter *at all*. The `split` method returns a reference to an array, and you're assigning that reference to `arr`. The `split` method is unaware of the previous value of the variable - it operates entirely independently of what you happen to do with the value afterwards - so it's not just filling in part of an existing array.

If you want that sort of behaviour, you could use something like this:

```
String[] array = { " ", " ", " ", " " }; // Or fill however you want
String splitThis = "Hello, World, There";
String[] splitResults = splitThis.split(",");
System.arraycopy(splitResults, 0, array, 0,
                 Math.min(array.length, splitResults.length));
```

Or perhaps you want a `List<String>` so you can add items later:

```
String splitThis = "Hello, World, There";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(splitThis.split(","));
list.add(...);
```

Comment: So, if I want to add some more data, like date in the 3rd index of array, can I do it?

Comment: @user3759100: You can't add anything to the array returned by `split`, because arrays are of a fixed length - once an array has been created, you can't add to it regardless of where it came from. Perhaps you want a `List<String>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet-What a beautiful use of `Array.max()`! +1 for sure!

Comment: @shekharsuman: Whoops, it should have been `Math.min`, rather than `Math.max`!

Comment: @JonSkeet-hahaha!!!Sorry,Math.max() for the first notification! I also pointed wrong,SORRY!

Answer (score 1):

The new array will only have a length of **3**. The old array becomes invalid. Trying to write into position 4 of this new array will be out-of-bounds and causes the exception.

You will have to add the array items to a `List` before you can add new items.

Answer (score 0):

```
String splitThis = "Hello, World, There";
arr = splitThis.split(",");
```

This will create a new array and assign it to arr variable overriding the previously initialized array. New array will have three elements

```
arr[0] = "Hello"
arr[1] = " World"
arr[2] = " There"
```

`arr[3]` will throw exception.